# Create Wix Bootstrapper without using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wix, sharpdevelop, burn

I am working on a C# application that currently has a simple WiX installer to generate an MSI file.  This application requires prerequisite software (such as the .NET Framework 4) and I would like to build a WiX Bootstrapper that will install the prereqs before installing my MSI file.  I know Visual Studio has a Bootstrapper project template that is capable of creating a WiX bootstrapper executable, however I am developing with SharpDevelop 4.3.

I am wondering if there is a way to create and compile a burn bundle into a bootstrapper executable without using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a Burn based bootstrapper/chainer bundle, you only need WiX v3.6+. The `Bundle` element in a .wxs file is the place to start. It's just like the `Product` element in a .wxs file is the place to start a .msi file.

Visual Studio has a bootstrapper system but it has nothing to do with `Burn`.

Comment: I've got a .wxs file with the standard Bootstrapper Application and a Bundle element containing my chained packages.  How do I use Burn to create an output .exe?

Comment: Compile/link the .wxs file that is based on a `Bundle` like you'd compile/link all .wxs files and the output will be a `.exe`. Burn is included automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I think I've got the hang of it now.